# How Can I Get The Last N Values of A Column into An Array PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, date

I have a table in a MySQL database (level_records) which has 3 columns (id, date, reading). I want to get the most recent 20 readings (by date) into an array and then average them.

I have looked everywhere, but no one seems to have a scenario quite like mine.

I will be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: i don't believe you have not found a "a scenario quite like mine";. a sort with a limit is very common

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Find the Average of Differences of The Last N Readings of a Column PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334958/how-to-find-the-average-of-differences-of-the-last-n-readings-of-a-column-php-my)

Comment: Sorry about my slightly daft question, but there is actually quite a difference in what I was trying to do between the two questions, so this is not a repeat. Furthermore, I am sorry for posting a question that may be elsewhere, but I genuinely could not find 'a scenario quite like mine' anywhere else on the internet.Again, sorry, and I will aim to improve my quality of question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "latest" twenty records:

```
SELECT t.reading
  FROM level_records t
 ORDER BY t.date DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

That's the query to run from PHP. Just execute the query and fetch the rows from the resultset and store them in an array; I think there's an example of how to do just that in the PHP documentation.

Getting an average of values from an array is very straightforward. You can use "`array_sum`" to get the total, and then divide that by the number of elements in the array, easily returned by "`count`". (Be sure to consider the corner case when `count` returns 0, because you don't have a guarantee that your array will contain exactly 20 elements, or even 1 element.)

NOTE: If there can be duplicate values for `date`, then you probably want to make the result deterministic by adding another column in the ORDER BY clause...

```
SELECT t.reading
  FROM level_records t
 ORDER BY t.date DESC, t.id DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

---

If all you need is an average, you can bypass the monkey business of calculating the average in PHP, and just get the average in your query, using the `AVG()` aggregate function. e.g.

```
SELECT AVG(s.reading) AS avg_reading
  FROM ( SELECT t.reading
           FROM level_records t
          ORDER BY t.date DESC, t.id DESC
          LIMIT 20
       ) s
```