# How To Find the Average of Differences of The Last N Readings of a Column PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database (level_records) which has 3 columns (id, date, reading). I want to put the differences between the most recent 20 readings (by date) into an array and then average them, to find the average difference.

I have looked everywhere, but no one seems to have a scenario quite like mine.

I will be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: This is (*next to*) basic mathematics. To make an average of something, you add up the number of entries divided by the number of entries. For example: Using three sets of numbers, 10-20-30. Add those up (60) and divide by three, which gives you 20.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why would you do that when SQL has a built-in `AVG` function?

Comment: I'm just stating that if someone doesn't understand basic mathematics, then relying on a function won't help someone understand how a function actually works. @Barmar

Comment: @Dagon It's not quite the same. That question asked to average the readings, this one asks to average the differences between the ratings.

Comment: How exactly are you defining "the differences between"? The difference between the dates?

Comment: I think he means the differences between the values of the `readings` column.

Comment: I understand the mathematics of how to find a mean average, but the thing I do not know how to do is to find the difference between all of the readings, and put these 19 sets of differences into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(difference)
FROM (
    SELECT @next_reading - reading AS difference, @next_reading := reading
    FROM (SELECT reading
          FROM level_records
          ORDER BY date DESC
          LIMIT 20) AS recent20
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @next_reading := NULL) AS var
    ) AS recent_diffs
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a489e/3)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Much appreciated and sorry to everyone that I failed to realise that this question was already on the web!

Answer (score 0):

If we consider "differences" to be signed, and if we ignore/exclude any rows that have a NULL values of reading...

If you want to return just the values of the difference between a reading and the immediately preceding reading (to get the latest nineteen differences), then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT d.diff
  FROM ( SELECT e.reading - @prev_reading AS diff
              , @prev_reading                    AS prev_reading
              , @prev_reading := e.reading       AS reading
           FROM ( SELECT r.date
                       , r.reading
                    FROM level_records r
                   CROSS
                    JOIN (SELECT @prev_reading := NULL) p
                   ORDER BY r.date DESC
                   LIMIT 20
                ) e
          ORDER BY e.date ASC
       ) d
```

That'll get you the rows returned from MySQL and you can monkey with them in PHP however you want. (The question of how to monkey around with arrays in PHP is a question that doesn't really have anything to do with MySQL.)

If you want to know how to return rows from a SQL resultset into a PHP array, that doesn't really have anything to do with "latest twenty", "difference", or "average" at all. You'd use the same pattern you'd use for returning the result from any query. There's nothing at all unique about that, there are plenty of examples of that, (most of them unfortunately using the deprecated mysql_ interface; for new development, you want to use either PDO or mysqli_.

---

If you mean by "all 19 sets of differences" that you want to get the difference between a reading and every other reading, and do that for each reading, such that you get a total of 380 rows ( = 20 * (20-1) rows ) then:

```
SELECT a.reading - b.reading AS diff
     , a.id       AS a_id
     , a.date     AS a_date
     , a.reading  AS a_reading
     , b.id       AS b_id
     , b.date     AS b_date 
     , b.reading  AS b_reading 
  FROM ( SELECT aa.id
              , aa.date
              , aa.reading
           FROM level_record aa
          WHERE aa.reading IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY aa.date DESC, aa.id DESC
          LIMIT 20
       ) a
  JOIN ( SELECT bb.id
              , bb.date
              , bb.reading
           FROM level_record bb
          WHERE bb.reading IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY bb.date DESC, bb.id DESC
          LIMIT 20 
       ) b
 WHERE a.id <> b.id
 ORDER BY a.date DESC, b.date DESC
```

Sometimes, we only want differences in one direction, that is, if we have the difference between r13 and r15, we essentially already have the inverse, the difference between r15 and f13. And sometimes, it's more convenient to have the inverse copies.

What query you run really depends on what result set you want returned.

---

If the goal is to get an "average", then rather than monkeying with PHP arrays, we know that the average of the differences between the latest twenty readings will be the same as the difference between the first and last readings (in the latest twenty), divided by nineteen.

If we only want to return a row if there are at least twenty readings available, then something like this:

```
SELECT (l.reading - f.reading)/19 AS avg_difference
  FROM ( SELECT ll.reading
           FROM level_records ll
          WHERE ll.reading IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY ll.date DESC LIMIT 1
       ) l
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT ff.reading
          FROM level_records ff
         WHERE ff.reading IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY ff.date DESC LIMIT 19,1
       ) f
```

NOTE: That query will only return a row only if there are at least twenty rows with non-NULL values of reading in the level_records table.

For the more general case, if there are fewer than twenty rows in the table (i.e. fewer than nineteen differences) and we want an average of the differences between the latest available rows, we can do something like this:

```
SELECT (l.reading - f.reading)/f.cnt AS avg_difference
  FROM ( SELECT ll.reading
           FROM level_records ll
          WHERE ll.reading IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY ll.date DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) l
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT ee.reading
             , ee.cnt 
          FROM ( SELECT e.date
                      , e.reading
                      , (@i := @i + 1) AS cnt
                   FROM level_records e
                  CROSS
                   JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) i
                  WHERE e.reading IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY e.date DESC
                  LIMIT 20
               ) ee
         ORDER BY ee.date ASC
         LIMIT 1
       ) f
```

---

But, if we need to treat "differences" as unsigned (that is, we are taking the absolute value of the differences between the readings),

then we'd need to get the actual differences between the readings, and then average the absolute values of the differences...

then we could do make use of a MySQL user variable to keep track of the "previous" reading, and have that available when we process the next row, so we can get the difference between them, something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(d.abs_diff)
  FROM ( SELECT ABS(e.reading - @prev_reading)   AS abs_diff
              , @prev_reading                    AS prev_reading
              , @prev_reading := e.reading       AS reading
           FROM ( SELECT r.date
                       , r.reading
                    FROM level_records r
                   CROSS
                    JOIN (SELECT @prev_reading := NULL) p
                   ORDER BY r.date DESC
                   LIMIT 20
                ) e
          ORDER BY e.date ASC
       ) d
```